# Metro Live Tile Like Twitter Feed with MetroJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am currently using the knockoutJS example for getting information from twitter.
I want to create a twitter feed on a [MetroJS](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) Live Tile. I Do get all the info, but the Live tile is not Cycling through the obtained twitter feeds.

Here is the HTML for the Live Tile

```
<div class="red">
<div id="tile1" data-mode="carousel" data-start-now="true" class="live-tile" data-direction="horizontal" data-delay="3000" data-bind='foreach: currentTweets' data-play-onhover="true">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img class="full" data-bind='attr: { src: profile_image_url }' alt=":(" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="tile-title"><a class='twitterUser' data-bind='attr: { href: "http://twitter.com/" + from_user }, text: from_user' href='http://twitter.com/${ from_user }'></a></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="metroExtraLarge" data-bind="text: text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/cDyWH/)** with the project example (Not sure how to add the Metrojs.js file to fiddle so that it works correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro JS grabs the tile faces as soon as .liveTile is called so the tile faces (or their containers at least) need to exist prior to calling .liveTile. You can call .liveTile after your content is bound or you could add some placeholder divs and pull a certain number of tweets.

There is also an animationComplete example on my site that uses a hidden html element as the datasource.
http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs#fiddle_9w98S